# cocos2dx - scheduleOnce not called

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scheduler, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am in a strange situation, I have some network calls in my application, and in the callback, I am showing a `Popup` of confirmation. The problem I am facing is the `Popup` doesn't show in the callback function, however same implementation work in other scene, but not in particular scene.

I thought calling Popup using scheduleOnce would solve, as it work on Main-Thread, but the schedular doesn't even call the function. See my implementation below..

```
void EndGame::joinRematchCallback(cocos2d::Ref *pSender,std::string msg){
    printf("\n rematch request received from %s",msg.c_str());
    this->msg=msg;

    scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(EndGame::showRematchPopup), 0.8f);

}

void EndGame::showRematchPopup(float dt){
    Size winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();


    POPUPDATA info;
    info.message=this->msg+" asked for Re-Match. Want to Join?";
    info.okAction=okAction("YES");
    info.cancelAction=cancelAction("NO");
    info.type=ALERT;
    info.TAG=GameTag::TAG_REMATCH_REQUEST;


    Popup *popup = Popup::create();
    popup->popupdata=info;
    popup->setActionCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(CommonScreen::popupActionCallback, GameEngine::getInstance()->activeScene));
    this->addChild(popup,5000);
    popup->createPopup();
}
```

The function `showRematchPopup` never called, however when I try to call the function using code below, it get called, but still my Popup doesn't work.

```
Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->schedule(schedule_selector(EndGame::showRematchPopup), this, 0.8f,0,0, false);
```

**`Popup`** works fine without any problem in all the scenes, not here.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: does schedule_selector product the appropriate method signature (you have a float parameter in your implementing method)? just asking, i dont know cpp , but in objC i would get the same result . I would need to [self scheduleOnce:@selector(showRematchPopup:) delay:.8f]  ... Notice the colon on the signature, it provides the appropriate signature. If cpp is same, the object does not implement the appropriate method, and thus there is no attempt to invoke the callback.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg you don't need to put colon in the end for the signature, in ios it is needed, everything is fine.. still doesn't work. If signature not correct in cpp it give compiletime error.

Comment: just curious (again based on objC experience) ... is your node in running state , ie has gone trough onEnter ... that would have same effect.

Comment: Yes, I have got some animations in the screen, all are working fine..